# Replace partitions

Tags: ubuntu, partition

I want to adjust the partition on my hard disk. I currently have a Windows partition and an Ubuntu 12.04 partition. I would like to remove the both partitions and install the latest version of Ubuntu to take the whole hard disk.

Does anyone have an explanation on how I can do this? Thanks.

Comment: I think this question is more apropriate for [Unix&Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to burn a live CD or to make an usb bootable drive of the latest version of ubuntu. Then, you have to save all your documents on an external disk drive or an usb key from both of your partitions.

Boot your PC with the live CD/USB in and install ubuntu. During the installation, when you reach "installation type" step, select "something else". An assistant will permit you to manage your futures partitions as you want. From my memories, it's very similar to GParted.